# Ruby On Rails | Blocked Host: localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I've been stuck on this issue for literally hours just trying to find the answer to this.

I start with the Mac Terminal `$ rails s` and it loads puma & works fine until I run into the problem attached in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Did you add "localhost" to config.hosts like it tell you? I believe it would go in `development.rb` file

Comment: I'm a beginner understanding the basics of ruby but while using replit, we now started using V.S but i don't know where to include 'config.hosts << localhost' my instructor's localhost is working fine so he didn't bother to explain this part to me.

Comment: This may be due to a bug as spickermann says, but just for future reference, the environment configuration would go in `development.rb`, `production.rb`, etc ... these files should already exist in your Rails project .. you can see there are many `config` lines in there and you'd just add another. But I would try updating your Rails as spickermann says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you running on a Ruby on Rails version that was released on the afternoon of 2021-12-14 – like `6.0.4.2`, `6.1.4.2`, and `7.0.0.rc2`?

Then you should just update to the versions released later in the night because those versions had a bug in their [default configuration](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2021/12/14/Rails-6-0-4-3-6-1-4-3-and-7-0-0-rc3-have-been-released/)

> There was a bug in the default configuration of the previous release such that requests in development with a port number wouldn’t be considered “authorized” requests. Requests to “localhost:3000” should work in this new version.

Updating Ruby on Rails to any of these versions `6.0.4.3`, `6.1.4.3`, and `7.0.0.rc3` should fix the bug.

---

**Update**: There was *another* bug in versions `6.0.4.3` and `6.1.4.3` regarding requests to `127.0.0.1:3000` and custom hosts. Therefore you need to update to [Rails `6.0.4.4` or `6.1.4.4`](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2021/12/15/Rails-6-0-4-4-and-6-1-4-4-have-been-released/) which were released on 2021-12-15 to finally fix this issue.